# Replace ** with Math.pow in SymPy

Tags: java, python, code-generation, sympy

I have a SymPy expression in Python and I would like to copy and paste it into a Java source code. Problem is that there’s a different notation for exponentiation:

- Java uses `Math.pow(a,b)`;
- Python uses `a**b`.

So my question is: Is there a way how to print the SymPy expression in the “Java format”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SymPy has several [code printers](//docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html) that are intended specifically for such a purpose. While there is no Java code printer, [there is one for Javascript](//docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/printing.html#module-sympy.printing.jscode). I cannot say whether Java and Javascript are sufficiently similar for every purpose, but exponentiation is printed the way you want it:

```
import sympy

a,b = sympy.symbols("a, b")

print(sympy.printing.jscode(a**b)) 
# 'Math.pow(a, b)'
```